# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 with Realm for WatchOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, realm, watchos-2

I want to add an AppleWatch-Extension to my current Projekt.
I´m using this podfile:

```
def shared_pods
    pod 'RealmSwift', '2.0.2'
end

target 'Target-iOS' do
  platform :ios, '9.0'
  use_frameworks!
  ...
  shared_pods
end

target 'Target-MensaWidget' do
  platform :ios, '9.0'
  use_frameworks!
  shared_pods
end

target 'Watch Extension' do
  platform :watchos, '2.0'
  use_frameworks!
  shared_pods
end
```

After `pod install` I will get this warning in my console:

```
[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:
```

When I try building the Project I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "realm::BpTreeBase::replace_root(std::__1::unique_ptr<realm::Array, std::__1::default_delete<realm::Array> >)", referenced from:
```

I also tried using $(inherited) in the Watch-Target.

I'am Using Xcode 7.3.1 and pod version 0.39.0

Any Ideas?

Comment: 'Generated duplicate UUIDs:' seems to be a relatively intermittent error with CocoaPods. There are a few workarounds here you might be able to try:  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4370

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error for Realm. 
I got rid of the error "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" by cleaning cocoapods cache:

```
pod cache clean --all
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me. ☺️

Comment: I did this but then I subbed in `pod install --repo-update`, then deleted my derived data, and closed and opened xcode.  Also cleaned the build.  Had to do all this and then it built!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most performant solution is to remove single Pod:

```
rm -rf Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/RealmJS
```

When you clean build, reinstall pods (pod deintegrate, rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods, rm -rf Pods) - then it takes much more time for new build.